# Query multiple post type and categories

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, query

I have a div and inside I wish display by random a post from category-a or a product from category-b. I'm looking for a query to do that.

I tried this:

```
 <?php
        $args = array( 
        'post_type' => array('product', 'post'), 
        'posts_per_page' => 1, 
        'cat' => 1,2, 
        'orderby' => 'RAND' 
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );       

        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

            <article class="promo">  

                    <div class="image">
                    <?php if (is_singular('product')){
                        echo 'Product';

                    }else{
                        echo 'Post';
                    }?>
                    </div>  


                </article>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Someone knows how to do that ?
thank you :)

**EDIT CODE**

```
    <?php
$args = [
    'post_type' => ['product','post'],
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields' => 'ids',
     'post_type' => ['product','post'],
'posts_per_page' => 2,
'fields' => 'ids',
'tax_query' => [

    'relation' => 'OR',
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => ['promo-distributeur', 'actu-distrib'],
    'include_children' => false,

]
    ]
];
$posts_ids = get_posts($args); 
$total = count($posts_ids);


if ($total > 0) { 
    $rnd = mt_rand(0, $total);
    $pid = $posts_ids[$rnd];
    $post = get_post( $pid);



while ( $post->have_posts() ) : $post>the_post(); global $product; ?>

            <article class="promo">  

                    <div class="image">
                    <?php if (is_singular('product')){
                        echo 'Product';

                    }else{
                        echo 'Post';
                    }?>
                    </div>  


                </article>
<?php endwhile;
} ?>
```

Comment: You can not limit the number of posts if you want to draw one of all posts. Change **2** to **-1** in `'posts_per_page' => 2`.   
if you want two random posts, execute this code twice `$rnd = mt_rand(0, $total)`.

Comment: Should it show only posts from cat A and products from cat B? Or can it show products from cat A also?

Comment: @nmr I change it but same error; "WP_Post::have_posts() in L:\wamp\www\tof_sof\wp-content\themes\inumedia\template-parts\home\promos\promos.php on line 41" the error seems to be  here "while ( $post->have_posts() ) : $post>the_post(); global $product; ?>"

Comment: @Lust You can't use post as `WP_Query` and you try to do that...

Comment: @Lust $post variable is you WP_Post object. You can check post type that way `if ($post->post_type == 'product')`, get title `$post->post_title`.  [Check here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post)

Answer (score 1):

The following code selects IDs of all posts type `product` and `post`, which belong to terms `category-a` or `category-b`, with `taxonomy_01` and `taxonomy_02`, respectively.

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => ['product','post'],
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'tax_query' => [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_01',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'category-a',
            'include_children' => false,
        ],
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_02',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'category-b',
            // OR by id
            //'field' => 'term_id', // default value
            //'terms' => 2,
            'include_children' => false,
        ],
    ]
];
$posts_ids = get_posts($args); 
$total = count($posts_ids);
if ($total > 0) { 
    $rnd = mt_rand(0, $total - 1);
    $pid = $posts_ids[$rnd];
    $my_post = get_post( $pid);
    // display post
}
```

I assume that the terms `category-a`, `category-b` belongs to different taxonomies. If not, then the `tax_query` should be:

```
'tax_query' => [
    [
        'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_01',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => ['category-a', 'category-b'],
        'include_children' => false,
    ],
]
```

**UPDATE**
I changed variable in the above code from `$post` to `my_post`.  Your code:

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => ['product','post'],
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'tax_query' => [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_01',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'category-a',
            'include_children' => false,
        ],
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_02',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'category-b',
            // OR by id
            //'field' => 'term_id', // default value
            //'terms' => 2,
            'include_children' => false,
        ],
    ]
];
$posts_ids = get_posts($args); 
$total = count($posts_ids);
if ($total > 0) {
    // get random post_ID 
    $rnd = mt_rand(0, $total - 1);
    $pid = $posts_ids[$rnd];
    $my_post = get_post( $pid);

    // display post
    if ( !empty($my_post) ) : ?>

        <article class="promo">  
            <div class="image">
            <?php 
                if ( $my_post->post_type == 'product' )
                    echo 'Product';
                else
                    echo 'Post';
            ?>
           </div>  
       </article>
   <?php endif;
}
```

Comment: thank you this help a lot :) 

I just have an error "Call to undefined method WP_Post::have_posts()"

I edit my first post with your solution to see what is wrong

Comment: Wow... You really want to select all posts and then randomize them in PHP? What if there will be many many posts?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Only the ID (not all fields) of those assigned to the `category-a` or `category-b`, as indicated in the question.

Comment: @nmr that's not what I was asking... ;) Sorry, if my question wasn't clear enough. Should it select posts from category B and products from category A also?

Comment: @ krysiek actually this section is just "temporary posts" my customer wil use it to display some promotions on his shop, it's ephemeral products until it's out of stock for example. so I will not have lot of products in this div may be 3 or 4 maximum at the same time

Answer (score -1):

you don't need global $product, and is_singular() is a template function, not usable in the loop, also if you pick only 1 post your orderby rand will not work since the subset of records is always the same 1 element

```
<div class="image">
   <?php 
    if ($post->post_type=='product'){
      echo 'Product';
       }
   else{
        echo 'Post';
        }?>
 </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but the second part of your answer (regarding orderby) is simply not true. The orderby is processed before limiting posts. That’s why you can get ten last posts using orderby date or 10 first posts in alphabetical order...

Comment: @Krzysiek Dróżdż right. sorry it was a wrong flash thought