# Get posts in taxonomy randomly

Tags: wp-query, templates, taxonomy, tax-query

I am having a query like this

**Code 1**

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
$args = array(
    'post_type'              => 'l',
    'post_status'            => array( 'published' ),
    'author_in'              => $authors,
    'posts_per_page'         => '1',
    'order'                  => 'ASC',
    'orderby'                => 'rand',
    'tax_query' => array(
array (
        'taxonomy'      => $term->taxonomy,
        'field'         => $term->slug,
        'terms'         => $term->term_id,

)
));
```

It just gives me one post . But if i use like below it works but i can't sort it by taxonomy terms.

**Code 2**

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
$args = array(
    'post_type'              => 'l',
    'post_status'            => array( 'published' ),
    'author_in'              => $authors,
    'posts_per_page'         => '1',
    'order'                  => 'ASC',
    'orderby'                => 'rand',
   );
```

I am using this is a template file :taxonomy-work.php.

I want it to make code 1 work but it rand doesn't seems to work unless i remove tax_query

Can it be done this way or do i have to look for something else? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error in `tax_query`.

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array (
        'taxonomy'      => $term->taxonomy,
        'field'         => 'term_id', // this is default value, so can be ommited
        'terms'         => $term->term_id,
    )
)
```

As you can read in [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters), possible values for `field` parameter are: `term_id` (default), `name`, `slug` or `term_taxonomy_id`.

In [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/309736/query-multiple-post-type-and-categories/309770#comment458019_309770) you can read about another method of getting a random post.

Comment: oh. I was working on my project with this error for more than a month.Thanks for clearing out :)